# Opengl Texture Transparency .BMP

Tags: opengl, transparency, textures

I am drawing a polygon with texture on it as part of the HUD in my OpenGL program.

```
//Change the projection so that it is suitable for drawing HUD
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  //Change the projection
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 800, 800, 0, -1, 1);  //2D Mode
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  //Back to modeling
glLoadIdentity();

//Draw the polygon with the texture on it
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(250.0, 680, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(570.0, 680, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(570.0, 800, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(250.0, 800, 0.0);
glEnd();

//Change the projection back to how it was before
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  //Change the projection
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, ((GLfloat)800) / GLfloat(800), 1.0, 200.0);  //3D Mode
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  //Back to modeling
glLoadIdentity();
```

The problem is that I can't get the "box" around the image to blend with the background. I opened the image (.bmp) in Photoshop and deleted the pixels around the image that I want displayed, but it still draws the whole rectangular image. It colors the pixels that I deleted with the last color that I used with glColor3f(), and I can get the whole image to become transparent, but I only want the pixels that I deleted in Photoshop to be transparent.
Any suggestions?

Properties that I am using for the textures:

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, TextureList[i]->getSizeX(), TextureList[i]->getSizeY(), GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureList[i]->getData());
```

Here's an image of my program. I'm trying to get the white box to disappear, but as I decrease the alpha with glColor4f(), the whole image fades instead of just the white box. 
img607.imageshack.us/img607/51/ogly.png

Code that loads a texture from file:

```
texture::texture(string filename)
{
// Routine to read a bitmap file.
// Works only for uncompressed bmp files of 24-bit color.
// Both width and height must be powers of 2.
unsigned int size, offset, headerSize;

// Read input file name.
ifstream infile(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

// Get the starting point of the image data.
infile.seekg(10);
infile.read((char *) &offset, 4);

// Get the header size of the bitmap.
infile.read((char *) &headerSize,4);

// Get width and height values in the bitmap header.
infile.seekg(18);
infile.read( (char *) &sizeX, 4);
infile.read( (char *) &sizeY, 4);

// Allocate buffer for the image.
size = sizeX * sizeY * 24;
data = new unsigned char[size];

// Read bitmap data.
infile.seekg(offset);
infile.read((char *) data , size);

// Reverse color from bgr to rgb.
int temp;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
{ 
temp = data[i];
data[i] = data[i+2];
data[i+2] = temp;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you have `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` set to?  What about `GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`?

Comment: I added the properties that I am using for the textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a glEnable(GL_BLEND) or a [glBlendFunc](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) in your code. Are you doing this?

Also, do you have an alpha channel in your image?

EDIT: You're loading the texture with the format GL_RGB, you're telling OpenGL there is no alpha on this texture.

1. You need to make an image with alpha transparency. Look here for a [GIMP](http://mcapewell.wordpress.com/2006/09/07/how-to-make-a-transparent-png-image-for-ie-6-in-the-gimp/) tutorial or here for a [Photoshop](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-misc001.html) tutorial.
2. Now load the texture indicating the correct image formats. There are MANY tutorials for "opengl alpha blending" on the internet - [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQtwIwADgK&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chbjxTmbQes&ei=7IHHUIXgG9G42gWLsYHADQ&usg=AFQjCNHy9D07cOpiu_WTZlpgtHUmXnFLqQ&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.b2I) is a C++ and SDL video tutorial.

Hope this helps!

Comment: An alpha channel seems to be an issue, but I still can't get it to work no matter what I do in Photoshop with it. Do you know of any tutorials that might help? I am using glBlend as Stephan specified. Here's an image of my program. I'm trying to get the white box to disappear, but as I decrease the alpha with glColor4f(), the whole image fades instead of just the white box.

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/51/ogly.png

Comment: Please provide us the actual texture (image file) you're using - if the blend state is set up correctly, it is probably the texture itself that is messed up. Also - please post the section of code that loads the texture from file. It is also possible that you don't give OpenGL the correct pixel format.

Comment: Here is the original image, though it was originally in .bmp and got converted to .png when I uploaded it...

http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/503/11450210.png

I tried that Photoshop tutorial, but whenever I try to save it in .bmp format, it fills in the pixels I deleted with a white background.

Comment: Your PNG doesn't have an alpha channel. See this (http://www.softcity.com/article/creative/how-to-create-with-photoshop-a-bmp-file-with-transparency/zMTOwEzN) tutorial on how to save a BMP with alpha. Also - your loading code assumes a 24 bit bpp format (RGB only). You'll need to modify it to load 32 bit bpp BMPs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want transparency to work with your textures, yes?
If so, change

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, TextureList[i]->getSizeX(), TextureList[i]->getSizeY(), GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureList[i]->getData());
```

to

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, TextureList[i]->getSizeX(), TextureList[i]->getSizeY(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureList[i]->getData());
```

To allow for an alpha channel, and turn on blending with:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**UPDATE**
As far as I know, <del>BMPs don't support transparency</del> (they can, ananthonline corrected me in the comments, but your application must support this) you should try one of the following formats if your imag editor does not support BMPs with alpha:

- PNG
- TIFF (recent variations)
- TARGA

Comment: Here's an image of my program. I'm trying to get the white box to disappear, but as I decrease the alpha with glColor4f(), the whole image fades instead of just the white box.

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/51/ogly.png

Comment: @user1136506 You need to make sure your image itself has an alpha channel and a transparent background (do this in your photoshop). Also make sure your 'gluBuild2DMipmaps' call is using GL_RGBA.

Comment: @user1136506 I fixed a typo in my gluBuild2DMipmaps call, try that out please.

Comment: @StephanvandenHeuvel BMPs DO support alpha. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format. But this is not very common.

Comment: @ananthonline oh good call. Thanks for the info. I guess the trick will be if the OP's software supports creating a BMP with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

To use the transparency channel (alpha channel) you need both to generate the BMP file with this channel (Photoshop does this if you ask him to), and specify the correct format when generating the mipmaps and sending the image to the video card.

This way, the image will have the needed transparency info and the OpenGl driver will know that the image has this info.

Comment: An alpha channel seems to be an issue, but I still can't get it to work no matter what I do in Photoshop with it. Do you know of any tutorials that might help? Here's an image of my program. I'm trying to get the white box to disappear, but as I decrease the alpha with glColor4f(), the whole image fades instead of just the white box.

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/51/ogly.png

Comment: There are a few other issues with your code. The second parameter of `gluBuild2DMipmaps` should be one of GLU_* constants, not a GL_*. Also, try to use GLU_RGBA or GLU_RGBA8 instead of GL_RGB. Take a look here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluBuild2DMipmaps.xml